# CKEditor Source Dialog shows HTML entities that are not stored in the database

Tags: html, character-encoding, ckeditor

When I click the 'Source' button on the menu bar, I see the HTML source of the page but it's showing the code as follows:

```
<p>This&#32;is&#32;how&#32;the&#32;code&#32;is&#32;showing&#32;now</p>
```

When I want to show it like this:

```
<p>This is how the code should be showing</p>
```

I thought it was storing it in the database that way but it's not. What needs to change in the `config.js` file for me to view the source correctly?

**EDIT**

Here's my complete `config.js` file:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

        config.language = 'en';
        config.uiColor = '#ededed';
        config.height = 500;
        config.toolbarCanCollapse = false;
        config.extraPlugins = 'font,justify,liststyle,filebrowser,colorbutton,panelbutton';
        config.allowedContent = true;

     config.toolbarGroups = [
          { name: 'document',        groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
          { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
          { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
          { name: 'liststyle' },
          { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
          { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
          { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
          { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
          { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
          { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
          { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
          { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
          { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
          { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] },
          { name: 'tabletools' }
        ];

        config.removeButtons = 'About';
        config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is [HTML Entity](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html) for space. Most likely you have used below configuration in your editor:

```
        var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
            entities_additional : '#32'
        });
```

In `config.js` this will look like: `config.entities_additional = '#32';`

Comment: See my edit above. I do not see that code in my `config.js` file.

Comment: **Have you got any extra editor configuration on HTML page?** Your configuration looks standard and none of these settings should cause entities to show up. **In which browser does it happen? Could you try disabling custom plugins and see if it makes any difference?** Some custom browser plugins may change how JavaScript application behave or even break them. **Finally could you check your third-party scripts?** Maybe you have a script which changes spaces to entities or maybe you have editor listener created somewhere which does that when editor mode is changed?